# How to center 2 slides in Slick carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, slick.js

I use [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) in my project and I need to center two slides. Unfortunately `centerMode` option works only with odd numbered `slidesToShow` counts. I tried to center active slides by CSS but without effects.

Do you know any solution? Thank you in advance!

---

Edit:

Example of my carousel: https://jsfiddle.net/lukaszflorczak/y7t64oqs/.

I want to have 1 centered item on the smallers screens, next 2, 3 etc. Not active slides have less opacity.

Comment: I don't think slick carousel is designed to center 2 slides. Its either you find another carousel that offers what you want to do or make your own carousel.

Comment: I know Slick doesn't have this option by default. The problem is I use Slick now in few other place in the project and I would like to do all carousels with one plugin. From one of Slick contributors I have info: „there's a way to determine the center two active slides with both css and js” but without details. So I hope someone here knows a solution :)

Comment: Please post a working sample of your code you have made so far so that we can find a way to solve your problem.

Comment: I added an example in the main post.

Answer (score 3):

Slick Carousel center Mode with two slides is possible using `variableWidth`, you have to set width for each slide. After that you have to move `slick-track` half width of the slick slide.

Working fiddle here:
[Slick slide - two slides in center mode](https://jsfiddle.net/3vchnp67/)

Answer (score 0):

Slick Carousel slides can be centered by setting the horizontal margins of `.slick-track` to `auto` in addition to using the `centerMode` attribute.

```
.slick-track {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INIT Event to add a css class if there are less items than "slidesToShow".

```
let slider = $('.reference-slider');

let slidesToShow = 3;

slider.on('init',function(event, slick, currentSlide){

    if (slick.$slides.length < slidesToShow) {
        $(this).find('.slick-track').addClass('slick-track-less-than-slidesToShow');
    }

});

slider.slick({
    slidesToShow: slidesToShow,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    fade: false,
    dots: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '0px',
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
});
```

Than add Style to the slick-track element:

```
   .slick-track.slick-track-less-than-slidesToShow {
       margin-left: 0;
   }
```